# How to compare multiple variables in an if statement?

Tags: ios, variables, if-statement, var

I have multiple variables:

1. `var1`
2. `var2`
3. `var3`

How can I check if any of the variables is less than 0, in one single line of code without separating it into 3 `if` statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you mean OR:

```
if (var1 < 0 || var2 < 0 || var3 < 0) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (var1 < 0 || var2 < 0 || var3 < 0) {
}
```